# reference help needed on a fact about poles of L-functions

Tags: l-functions

Suppose $\pi$ and $\rho$ are cuspidal automorphic representations on $GL(n)$ and $GL(m)$ respectively. Then the L-function $L(s,\pi \times \rho)$ has a pole iff and $m=n$ and $\pi$ is isomorphic to the contragradient of  $\rho$ by some twist. Does anyone know some reference containing the proof of this fact?

I checked Rankin-Selberg convolution paper by Jacquet-P.S-Shalika. It mentioned this result and said the proof would appear somewhere.

Many thanks.

Comment: I'm also curious, but not so curious right now to pore through the literature.  It seems that the J-PS-S paper was followed up by archimidean results by J (Contemp. Math.) and J-S (in the PS 60th bday volume).  Perhaps these finish it off?  Also, Cogdell's article "Analytic theory of L-functions for GL(n)" (on his webpage) has an exposition of this result.  I don't know which of these or other articles is the definitive reference for this important result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to be in the Cogdell-PS paper "Remarks on Rankin-Selberg Convolutions" in the Shalika volume, though I haven't read through it myself.

Comment: Since this question just became active again, I thought I'd add this (which surely the OP knew): when $m=n$, this was already in Jacquet-Shalika's "On Euler Products... I" paper, so the only thing needed was the $m < n$ case.

Answer (score 3):

See also

C. Mœglin and J.-L. Waldspurger, *Poles des fonctions L de paires pour GL(N),* Appendice, Ann. Sci. École Norm. Sup. (4) **22** (1989), 667–674.